# View.post() not called?

Tags: android

I am making an Image loader for loading images into lists - so in order it to be smooth, everything needs to run in the background thread except setting the image to the view.
The problem is that the Runnable in the code bellow is sometimes not executed.
I am calling the setImage method from background threads.

```
protected void setImage(final ImageView img, final Bitmap bm, String hash) {
    img.setTag(TAG_RESPONSE, hash);
    Log.v(TAG, "setting image bitmap1");
    //TODO: here is the bug - sometimes the runnable below is not called
    img.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.v(TAG, "setting image bitmap2");
            img.setImageBitmap(bm);
            img.invalidate();
        }
    });

}
```

Anyone has any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29), the post(...) should be called from non-UI threads only when the View is attached to a window. This could be the problem.

Comment: I replaced the View.post with Handler.post and it seems to work like butter now.

Comment: In my case `View.post` was working in `Android 7` but not working in `Android 4`.  I followed the following link and `Handler.post` worked for me too: [link](https://techblog.appnexus.com/weird-android-bug-160d76dd7bc) As link says, I created handler like: `Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());`