# Popup Window call within onCreate method

Tags: android, popupwindow, layout-inflater

I would like to display a Popup Window when the activity is created. 
I have followed [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730281/android-popup-window-call-from-oncreate/14731002) regarding this which recommend putting some of the code within a post method. Currently i have;

```
    final PopupWindow poppers = new PopupWindow(this);
    final View popLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.content_popup, null);
    poppers.setContentView(popLayout);

    poppers.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    poppers.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    poppers.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

    poppers.setFocusable(true);
    poppers.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    poppers.setElevation(3);

    popLayout.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {

            poppers.showAtLocation(llMain, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }
```

The code within run() is never hit. Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: `llMain` is Main root view ?

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544732/view-post-not-called) post.

Comment: @SagarJethva yes it is.

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee thank you for finding. Unfortunately when using a Handler instead of post i get a BadTokenException as the activity has not fully set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it as below

```
 llMain.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {

            poppers.showAtLocation(llMain, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }
```

> instead of popLayout use your rootView.

Comment: Using the rootView llMain instead of popLayout worked perfectly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
    try this and declare this first      PopupWindow popupWindow;


     LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) HomeActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home,null);
            //instantiate popup window
             popupWindow = new PopupWindow(customView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

 //display the popup window
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(binding.llMain, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);



But I suggest use custom Dialog:

public class FilterDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener{
    DialogMatchBinding binding;
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public FilterDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.PauseDialogAnimation;
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.dialog_match, null, false);
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transparent);
        // set click listner

    }

}
```